# How to find redistributable is needed?

Tags: c#, redistributable

I made C# program that talks to Systec CAN module using .dll
given by that company: CANopenDotNET.dll and cdrvwrap.dll.

Problem is that all works fine on my PC but on client one that .dll is not visible
somehow, or do not includes.

Only solution I found to make it work is to install VS2013 Community edition,
but that is not an option on clients PC.

Maybe you know how to find what framework/redistributable is used during program
execution. Then I can find that on my PC easily and install on client one.

Regards,
Chris

Comment: Hello.How are you distributing your app?

Comment: You have to [RTFM](https://www.systec-electronic.com/media/default/Redakteur/produkte/Interfaces_Gateways/sysWORXX_USB_CAN_module_1/CANopen_API_for_.NET_-_Software_Manual.pdf), chapter 1.3